# Mercurial revset for finding next tag after a commit

Tags: mercurial

How do I find the *next tag* after a specific changeset revision?

For example if a bug was introduced in changeset `abcdef123456`, how do I find the first release (tag) that included this bug?

I assume I can use [HG revsets](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/help/revsets) for this somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hg log -r "first(abcdef123456:: and tag())"`

---

Or for filtering releases to tags that match a special regular expression:

`hg log -r "first(abcdef123456:: and tag(r're:Release'))"`