# How can I find out which release is associated with a commit in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'm looking at a bug fix commit in a Mercurial repository. I have no experience with Mercurial but I need to find out the answer to:

"Which release is the first release that has the patch applied for this bug?"

In other words, I'm trying to find out which release, if any, fixes a particular bug in a project tracked by Mercurial.

For Git, I will sometimes view tags and find out the nearest tag associated with the patch commit. Can I do this in Mercurial also or is there another convention used?

Comment: I think you can use `hg tags` to view the nearest tag associated with that patch commit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mercurial revset for finding next tag after a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59409786/mercurial-revset-for-finding-next-tag-after-a-commit)